# What font is this (taken from a specific pdf)?

Tags: fonts

What is the name of the font on the second page of [this pdf](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/ba-a4.pdf) used for the word "preface"?  (reproduced below in case the link dies eventually)
I've already tried automatic font finders, to no avail.

[image: Preface]

Comment: I should clarify that I've already done that, to no avail @Werner

Comment: @DrewBrady: You can probably replicate it using `\chapter*{Preface}` in `\documentclass{book}`.

Comment: I believe that will just use the standard computer roman font, which is not correct, @Werner.

Comment: @DrewBrady Why are you convinced it's not computer roman? running pdffonts on the pdf shows that it's CMB10..

Comment: Well, @Troy, visual inspection will tell you it is not directly CMB or CMR (10). If it is CMB/CMR10, then it certainly squished or something. Not sure the best way to test that out.

Comment: Looks correct to me: https://ufonts.com/fonts/cmb10.html. can you point out a particular discrepancy that you are seeing between your picture and this link?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is CMB10.

Comment: You're right, it is. I didn't realize that textbf did not produce the same thing as cmb10. Is it easy to explain how to make textbf produce cmb10? If not, I can ask separately.

Comment: (It is \font\textbf=cmb10)

Comment: Usually `\chapter*{Preface}` will produce **Bold Extended** font, which is CMBX10 or CMBX12 (as the case may be).  To change from CMBX.. to CMB.. (which is simply **Bold** and _not extended_) you can use `\chapter*{\fontseries{b}\selectfont Preface}` to get the desired output.